# Left invariant vector field : does it depends on the choice of the left translation function?

Tags: differential-geometry

In my course, we define the left invariant vector fields as vector fields that verify :

$$ \forall g ~ L_{a*} X(g) = X(ag) $$

Where $L_{a*}$ is the push forward associated to the left translation function.

But here it seems that the qualification of left invariant vector field depends on $a$.

So my question is : in fact can we prove that if for a given $a$ I have a left invariant vector field, it is true for any $a$ ?

Comment: Are you shure you have the definition right? I think it should be : $\forall a ~ L_{a*} X(e) = X(a)$. From that definition it follows from the group composition law that : $\forall h ~ L_{a*} X(h) = X(a.h)$

Comment: Yes my definition was indeed incomplete, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the commutative Lie group $\mathbb{R}^n$. Each vector field of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is invariant by $L_0$ since it is the identity, but it is not always invariant by every translation. Just the constant vector fields here are left invariant.

Comment: Yes ok. But is my definition incomplete ? Do we call a left invariant vector field a vector field that will satisfy my proposition for **any** $a$ ?

Comment: Yes, it has to be true for any $a$.